# Migrating 2 contracts in one Contract.sol script using 'truffle migrate'

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain

I have 2 contracts in 1 .sol file and when I run 'truffle migrate', it tells me that it has deployed 1 of the contracts and given me an additional error:

> Blockquote

```
Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 4!
```

Here is my 2_intitail_migration.js file

```
const AuctionBox = artifacts.require("AuctionBox");
const Auction = artifacts.require("Auction");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(AuctionBox);
  deployer.deploy(Auction);
};
```

How can I got about it?

[image]

Comment: `Auction` takes 4 arguments at construction. What part of that have you failed to understand from the error message???

Comment: If the number of parameters is correct another thing you can try is to delete the build/ directory, sometimes truffle gets confused and doesn't update it correctly.

Comment: I just realized the parameter thing now but I am still not able to set it right. The AuctionBos is call the Auction contract which has 4 parameters. Both contracts are on the same script .sol.